# Is there a way to check system privacy settings of other application (e.g. Facebook)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdksharekit

I build application which allows to share video through Facebook by share dialog:

```
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoAssetUrl;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;


[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:nil
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:self];
```

The variable named videoAssetUrl stores link to a video from Photos. Access to photos from my application requested before this properly.

But if Facebook does not have access to Photos dialog is displayed without the video (and without any errors).

[image]

How to check the settings and prevent this undesirable behavior?

Comment: Check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult/  (@property (copy, nonatomic) NSSet *grantedPermissions; -   Declared In: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult.h)

Comment: The OP is referring to OS level permissions and not to Facebook Login permissions